# использование workbook в методе read_excel/ExcelFile

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

```
wb = load_workbook('Dampers.xlsm')
xlsm = pd.ExcelFile(how?)
onedparts_referense_df = pd.read_excel(how?)
```

Как мне прочитать excel, которую я уже загрузил с помощью load_workbook?

Дело в том, что после load_workbook я изменяю динамические диапазоны и мне нужно после изменений в файле продолжить с ним работу не сохраняя (сохранять не нужно, да и долго это из-за веса файла).

Answer (score 0):

Решение лежало на поверхности библиотеки xlwings.
Подключаемся к файлу excel.

```
        app = app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book = False)
        wb = app.books.open(путь к файлу)
```

Меняем диапазон

```
wb.names("Наименование динамического диапазона").refers_to = переменная
```